# Like in Lambda Expression and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I do something like this using Expression trees :

```
customers.Where(c => c.Name **like** "john");
```

I know this isn't possible but I was wondering how can I have something similar.

Note : I'm **NOT** looking for solutions using SQL related LINQ queries (like Linq to SQL or Linq to entities)

Comment: Actually you can generate like statements. Look [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx) and [here](http://www.simonrhart.com/2008/06/using-like-in-linq-to-sql-under-c.html) for a good examples.

Comment: If you use LINQ to SQL, choose @Johannes's answer; otherwise - @Tom's one.

Comment: actually im not using LINQ to SQL NeitherLINQ to anything im using Expression trees, and im building my own API , so i was wondering how its done in Lambda expression , any way i will try to translate the "containt" expression and see if it will work. thanks all.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
customers.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("john"));
```

Comment: +1. Perfect. Works with both LINQ over enumerables (LINQ to Object) as LINQ over expression trees (LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, etc).

Comment: isn't it case sensitive ?

Answer (score 31):

If you are targeting LINQ to SQL, use [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx):

```
customers.Where(c => SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, "%john%"));
```

Explanation:

The compiler will generate an expression tree from the statement above. Since `LIKE` is a SQL specific construct and not common to all LINQ Query providers, the `SqlMethods` class and its members are used as a "hint" for the expression compiler (compiles expression trees to SQL) to emit a `LIKE` statement.

Comment: This will (of course) only work with LINQ to SQL, not with LINQ to Entities nor with 'LINQ to Enumerable' a.k.a. LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that he's using LinqToSql. I felt using string.contains is just too obvious?!

Answer (score 10):

The first thought that comes to mind is [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx).

This would come closest to providing the kind of functionality you get from `LIKE`; for instance with it you could do this:

```
var matches = people.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p.Name, "A.*[mn]"));

foreach (Person match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Name);
}
```

And get output like this:

```
Adam
Aaron
Aidan
```

Going with [`string.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) as others have suggested is almost certainly preferable if your intention is simply to look for a specific substring within `Name`.

Comment: and now you have _two_ problems :).

Comment: @Phil: Indeed, I don't know how I feel about even posting this answer. I'm leaving it as an option, anyway. Maybe someone will come along and point out that it is a horrible suggestion; I don't know.

Comment: @Michael, it's not a horrible suggestion I'm just refering to a famous quote: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.*

Comment: Oh, I see. Knowing RegExes I even understand why the quote got famous :-)

Comment: @PhilGan I love this joke. It's funny because it's true and it's sophisticated because it's exclusive to quite a small portion on the individuals walking on this planet.

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;
...
customers.where(c=>SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, "john"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Regex.IsMatch` in your where statement or for a more simpler version without wildcards etc.:

```
customers.where(c=>c.Name.Contains("john"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code :

```
string s="somethings";

customers.Where(c => c.Name != null && c.Name.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()));
```

Somethings like that.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
customers.where(c=>EF.Functions.Like(c.Name,"%john%");
```

I did a test to see the generated sql and this was the result

```
sql = _context.ProdutoPortfolio.Take(10).Where(c => c.NomeProduto.Contains(c.NomeProduto))

sql2 = _context.ProdutoPortfolio.Take(10).Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.NomeProduto, $"%{search}%")
```

**Result sql1: If you use contains this is the result**

```
DECLARE @__p_0 int = 10;
DECLARE @__search_1 varchar(350) = 'a';

 

SELECT [t].[ProductID], [t].[Cod], [t].[ProductName], [t].[SubThemeName], [t].[ThemeName]
FROM (
     SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [p].[ProductID], [p].[Cod], [p].[ProductName], [p].[SubThemeName], [p].[ThemeName]
     FROM [ProductPortfolio] AS [p]
) AS [t]
WHERE (@__search_1 LIKE '') OR (CHARINDEX(@__search_1, [t].[productName]) > 0)
```

**Result sql2:**

```
DECLARE @__p_0 int = 10;
DECLARE @__Format_2 varchar(350) = '%a%';

 

SELECT [t].[ProductID], [t].[Cod], [t].[ProductName], [t].[SubThemeName], [t].[ThemeName]
FROM (
     SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [p].[ProductID], [p].[Cod], [p].[ProductName], [p].[SubThemeName], [p].[ThemeName]
     FROM [ProductPortfolio] AS [p]
) AS [t]
WHERE [t].[productname] LIKE @__Format_2
```

SQL2 meets what I want, SQL2 wins

Comment: While your answer looks correct to me, it'd help if you added context to explain (for example) what `EF.Functions.Like` is, where it comes from, how it is different (or not) from other answers...

Comment: @nalka i atualized my test, you can read again

Comment: They're explicitly not asking for a LINQ-to-anything solution, so no EF. See the comments. Which means that the answer using `Contains` is all they need.

Comment: Not necessarily. As you can see in the tests above, contains is not case sensitive and does not pick up words at the beginning of the sentence because it does not use 'like'

Comment: `Contains` *is* case-sensitive and *does* "pick up" words at the beginning of a string in LINQ-to-objects, which is what the question is about.

Comment: You can try but (CHARINDEX(@__search_1, [t].[productName]) > 0) is diferent of LIKE