# Like condition in LINQ

Tags: linq, sql-like

I am relatively new to LINQ and don't know how to do a Like condition.  I have an IEnumerable list of myObject and want to do something like myObject.Description like 'Help%'.  How can I accomplish this?  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Like in Lambda Expression and LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616215/like-in-lambda-expression-and-linq)

Comment: @All....thanks for the comments and answers.  Very useful and helpful......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx

*Snippet:*

`StartsWith` and `Contains`:

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where c.City.StartsWith("L") && c.City.Contains("n")
            select c;
```

And if you should use it with LINQ to SQL (does not work with LINQ to Objects):

Custom `LIKE` (`System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like`):

```
var query = from c in ctx.Customers
            where SqlMethods.Like(c.City, "L_n%")
            select c;
```

Answer (score 5):

You generally use the exact same syntax you'd use outside a query.

```
myObject.Description.StartsWith("Help")
```

Whether this actually works depends on where you're using LINQ (it might either be ran as code, in which case everything works, or get converted to something like else, such as SQL, which might have limitations), though, but it's always worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx), [EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx), or [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx) depending where you want to check:

```
var result = from o in myCollection
             where o.Description.StartsWith("Help")
             select o;
```

You can optionally pass a StringComparison to specify whether to ignore case or not (for `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`) which would make the operation behave more like a SQL query:

```
var result =
    from o in myCollection
    where o.Description
        .StartsWith("Help", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    select o;
```

If you want to do a case insensitive contains, you need to use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) instead:

```
var result = 
    from o in myCollection
    where o.Description
        .IndexOf("Help", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0
    select o;
```

Comment: `StartsWith` and friends also let you specify the comparison type.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **string.StartsWith** or **string.EndsWith** or **string.Contains** property of string to use it as Like Operator. 
Startswith will work for Like 'A%'
Endswith will work for Like '%A'
Contains will work like '%A%'