# Like operator in LinQ to Entity MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I'm running a MVC4 website, where I want to filter by a search string.
I have a string that contains 2 parameters, with a blank space between, like following search string:

```
    "tha 19"
```

Currently I'm using

```
    .contains(searchString)
```

The problem is, that if the use only type "th 19" it won't find any result with contains, since contains is the complete string.
I have solved the problem with SQL by following:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM DB
    WHERE DB.Name LIKE 'th%19'
```

The %-operator between the blank spaces, do the works, and will find the specific entity, without the need of typing excatly name like: tha 19.

Is there an equal in LINQ to Entity of the %-operator in SQL?

EDIT: I have tryed to split the string into an string[] strArr, but the LINQ doesn't support ArrayIndex like strArr[0]... StartsWith() doesn't work either, because it take the complete string into considaration.

Comment: There are a couple of questions which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616215/like-in-lambda-expression-and-linq and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616215/like-in-lambda-expression-and-linq

Comment: There is a `Like` method tucked away... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx